# Listen on TCP4 not TCP6

Tags: go, ipv4, go-gin, goji

I am using https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin to write an http service
But when I deploy it, it keeps deploying on tcp6(according to netstat)

```
r := gin.Default()
//none of these are working , It keeps being listed on tcp6
r.Run(":8080")
r.Run("*:8080")
r.Run("0.0.0.0:8080")
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The documentation states

> Run attaches the router to a http.Server and starts listening and serving HTTP requests. It is a shortcut for http.ListenAndServe(addr, router)

You can start the server directly using an `http.Server` the same way the `http` package does in `ListenAndServe`

```
server := &http.Server{Handler: r}
l, err := net.Listen("tcp4", addr)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
err = server.Serve(l)
// ...
```